# Positioning a relative div to a fixed div

Tags: css

I have a header with an image which should be fixed while scrolling. Underneath I have a container, which should always have the same distance to the header. So if I resize my window horizontal, the image resizes and therefor the content changes the position.

Example:

I set the wrapper to `position:fixed;` and the container to `position:relative;`. If you resize the window, it works perfect.. the container stays in the same distance to the picture.. BUT.. I can't scroll anymore and therefore I can't see the content anymore. :-(

I have no idea how to use JS, so maybe someone could give me a hint

[Live Link](http://romantikhotel-wastlwirt.com/redesign-hotel.html)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Try making a codepen or jsfiddle that recreates the issue. You're significantly more likely to get assistance if you make the question easier / more attractive to answer for those that would be extending their wisdom to you for free.

Comment: Oh Sorry - I will change that next time-- making my question easier/more attractive - English is not my native language and I am more than glad, that i maanged to describe my problem the was I did :-( And thank you for sharing your wisdom :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any element that's fixed, has all of its children fixed as well. So anything in your wrapper will be locked, which is why you aren't able to scroll. If you remove fixed from the wrapper element, then your nav is still fixed and the body scrolls properly. From there, a little trick I like to use is something like this...

```
<figure class="image_container" style="background:url(files/Header/Haus_Sommer.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;background-size:cover;">
  <img src="files/Header/Haus_Sommer.jpg" width="1460" height="1000" alt="" style="opacity: 0;">
</figure>
```

That way, you can use background-attachment:fixed for the header image, and still get the scaling from the image tag itself, since it's just got the opacity set to 0 but is still present.

Comment: Thx.. The prob I have, is that every picture on over 200 pages is differnet..But I will keep your answer in mind.. it may come handy some other time... :-)

Comment: If you're willing to use a little javascript you could do something like $('.image_container').each(function(){ var myImg = $(this).children('img').attr('src'); $(this).attr('style','background:url('+myImg+') no-repeat bottom center fixed;background-size:cover;");});